# Buttons and Links are not working anymore

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, advanced-custom-fields

On a new project of mine; [Click!](http://test.hrprojectpartners.nl/)
All my buttons and links are looking disabled and stopped working. It's not just on the homepage but also on the blog page. Clicking in the inputs is also "disabled".. I tried the deactivate/active plugin debug solution, but unfortunately this gives me no results.

My WordPress templates are build with bootstrap and acf.

Thanks in advance,

Gino

Comment: what the console output when click

Comment: @kris Roofe The console in Element Inspect shows up nothing when i click on a button.

Comment: Looks like invisible parts of your nav menu are covering up everything. When i inspect a link in Chrome, all i get is something in the nav.

Comment: what is the css rules on the disabled button in your browser development env.

Comment: site link not working

Comment: @cHao Any idea why?

Comment: @KrisRoofe What do you mean?

Comment: @vel Still works here..

Comment: @Gino  press F12 and see the css rules on the button. get out which rule make it disabled.

Comment: @KrisRoofe It seems cHao is right. If i element inspect a button, it shows my navbar. My navbar is covering up everything. Any idea where to look/fix this?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead.

Comment: set css .navbar-yorem { height: 100px;}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set this style. The nav menu is covering up everything

```
.navbar-yorem {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 100px;
}
```